# Reuse TSQLQuery Missing Params

Tags: delphi, parsing, parameters, delphi-xe2

I'm using Delphi XE2 and a TSQLQuery object.  It works the first time that I use it.  If I immediately reuse it, then it doesn't parse the new SQL for its parameters and rebuild the `qry.Params` list:

```
var
  qry: TSQLQuery;
begin
  qry := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    qry.MaxBlobSize := -1;
    qry.SQLConnectin := AnExistingConnection;

    qry.CommandText := 'select field1 from table1 where fieldX = @valueX';
    qry.ParamByName('valueX').Value := 1;
    qry.Open;

    // ... use data ...

    qry.Close;
    qry.Params.Clear; // <- works the same with or without this
    qry.CommandText := 'select field2 from table2 where fieldY = @valueY';
    qry.ParamByName('valueY').Value := 2; // <- Error: 'valueY' Param not found
    qry.Open;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(qry);
  end;
end;
```

It doesn't matter what I do, it doesn't parse the 2nd SQL statement for its parameters so I can't bind the 'valueY' parameter by name.

I can think of two workarounds:

1. Manually build the `qry.Params` list myself.
2. Destroy and recreate the `qry` object in between the two commands.

I shouldn't have to do either of these.  Perhaps there is a property or something on the `qry` object that will cause it to reparse parameters each time a new SQL statement is assigned to its `CommandText` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out to be a syntax issue.  Params must be prefaced with a `:` not a `@`.  I had local SQL variables throughout the real first query, so there was a mixture of `@param` and `:param` variables throughout the SQL.  By using the `:param` syntax for all bound parameters, the `TSQLQuery` **does** properly parse the parameters each time, like it is supposed to do.

```
var
  qry: TSQLQuery;
begin
  qry := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    qry.MaxBlobSize := -1;
    qry.SQLConnectin := AnExistingConnection;

    qry.CommandText := 'select field1 from table1 where fieldX = :valueX';
    qry.ParamByName('valueX').Value := 1;
    qry.Open;

    // ... use data ...

    qry.Close;
    qry.CommandText := 'select field2 from table2 where fieldY = :valueY';
    qry.ParamByName('valueY').Value := 2;
    qry.Open;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(qry);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `TSQLQuery.SQL` property instead of the `TSQLQuery.CommandText` property:

```
qry.SQL.Text := 'select field1 from table1 where fieldX = @valueX'; 
...
qry.SQL.Text := 'select field2 from table2 where fieldY = @valueY';
```

No need to call `Params.Clear` in between, the `SQL` property will handle that for you.

Comment: Thanks @Remy.  I tried it without the `Params.Clear`, but it didn't help.  However, I found the problem in the last few minutes.  I'll post the answer...  Thanks for your time!